# JSON schema validation for null when "type"="string"

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I wanted to prevent a json filed from allowing null as a valid value for it.
Tried using the keyword **not**, but no luck.

Want the below json to be validated as false, as the field **stats** as value as null.

```
{
  "stats": "null"
}
```

please find my schema below:-

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "maxProperties": 1,
  "properties": {
    "stats": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/stats#",
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 5,
      "minLength": 2,
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "maxProperties": 1,
      "not": {"type":  "null"}
    }
  },

  "required": [
    "stats"
  ]
}
```

Though i gave **"not": {"type":  "null"}**, it still validated successfully.

Comment: I tried validating with `{ "stats" : "null" }` and it failed.  How are you validating your JSON?

Comment: Are you sure it's "null" not 'null'? For this is a String, not a 'null' value

Comment: I am using java code to validate the json, with jsonSchema.But I am checking the validation using http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#, to test in amuch easier way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow. So much confusion here.

The problem is simple:

```
{
  "stats": "null"
}
```

`"null"` is a string, thus it’s valid (because you allow strings). This would not be allowed by your schema, which works as you expect:

```
{
    stats: null
}
```

The answer from Ashish Patil is wrong: in your schema (not your data), when you are specifying the type, the type name is a string. Specifying `"not": {"type": null}` is not valid. You *could* specify `"not": {"type": "null"}`, but that would be redundant as the earlier `"type": "string"` already implies that.

The accepted answer from jruizaranguren works because it doesn’t allow the *string* `"null"`. It doesn’t address the core confusion that `null` is not the same as `"null"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "enum" keyword instead of "type". "null" is not a valid json and json-schema type.

Also additionalProperties and maxProperties are useless within stats description.

```
{
    "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id" : "http://jsonschema.net#",
    "type" : "object",
    "additionalProperties" : false,
    "maxProperties" : 1,
    "properties" : {
        "stats" : {
            "id" : "http://jsonschema.net/stats#",
            "type" : "string",
            "maxLength" : 5,
            "minLength" : 2
            "not" : {
                "enum" : ["null"]
            }

        }
    }, 
    "required" : [
        "stats"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks jruizaranguren. Works perfect

Comment: The word `enum` is not instead of "type", it goes along with it and defines set of possible values

Comment: That's True. It was a bad sentence.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, null is not a String. So try using below in your schema--

```
 "stats": {
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net/stats#",
  "type": "string",
  "maxLength": 5,
  "minLength": 2,
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "maxProperties": 1,
  "not": {"type":  null}
}
```

But, in the example snippet you have mentioned something like below--

`{
  "stats": "null"
}`

So, if you really wanted null to be not allowed in your file, then your example file should look like `{
  "stats": null
}`
Along schema i have provided.